# Replacing dots, commas and percentages marks with load `csv` file with `fread()`

Tags: r, data.table, gsub, fread

We would like to manage the columns from `csv` file with originally three `character` columns class when we used the `fread()` with the arguments detailed in the `R code used` section (separator and decimal arguments are specified). The R session version is `4.2.0` and the `data.table` version is `1.14.2`.

### *Input* data from `csv` file

```
col_1,col_2, col_3
/100.432,"30,84Â %","4,14"
/3.200,"62,89Â %","1,89"
/10.100,"50,00Â %","1,62"
/15.570, "40,10Â %","3,41"
/900.310, "8,00Â %","0,10"
```

### *Input* data in `R` session

```
> dat
# A tibble: 5 × 3
 
  col_1   col_2    col_3
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1 100.432 30,84 % 4,14 
2   3.200 62,89 % 1,89 
3  10.100 50,00 % 1,62 
4  15.570 40,10 % 3,41 
5 900.310  8,00 % 0,10
```

### R code used

```
data.table::fread(
  x,
  sep = ',',
  dec = '.',
  na.strings = c('', 'NA')) %>%
as_tibble()
```

### Desired *output* data

```
> dat
# A tibble: 5 × 3
 
 col_1   col_2  col_3
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 100438 30.84  4.14 
2   3200 62.89  1.89 
3  10100 50.00  1.62 
4  15570 40.10  3.41 
5 900310  8.00  0.10
```

### Question

We would like to obtain the `Desired output data` format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused: what is called "input data" looks like the current output. What I'd expect as input data is the corresponding sample of the CSV file.

Comment: Thank you @Aurèle to improve the estructure of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do some postprocessing in R:

```
RAW = fread('col_1,col_2, col_3
/100.432,"30,84Â %","4,14"
/3.200,"62,89Â %","1,89"
/10.100,"50,00Â %","1,62"
/15.570, "40,10Â %","3,41"
/900.310, "8,00Â %","0,10"')

#       col_1    col_2  col_3
#      <char>   <char> <char>
# 1: /100.432 30,84Â %   4,14
# 2:   /3.200 62,89Â %   1,89
# 3:  /10.100 50,00Â %   1,62
# 4:  /15.570 40,10Â %   3,41
# 5: /900.310  8,00Â %   0,10

library(readr)
RAW[, lapply(.SD, \(x) parse_number(x, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",")))]
# Or in base R:
RAW[, lapply(.SD, \(x) gsub("[^0-9.]", "", chartr(".,", "_.", x)) |> as.numeric())]

#     col_1 col_2 col_3
#     <num> <num> <num>
# 1: 100432 30.84  4.14
# 2:   3200 62.89  1.89
# 3:  10100 50.00  1.62
# 4:  15570 40.10  3.41
# 5: 900310  8.00  0.10
```

Comment: Both options work fine. Thanks so much @sindri_baldur

Answer (score 0):

I've improved the postprocessing proposed by @sindri_baldur. In `dplyr` version `1.0.9` the code should be:

### *Input* data from `csv` file

```
dat = data.table::fread(
 'col_1,col_2, col_3
 /100.432,"30,84Â %","4,14"
 /3.200,"62,89Â %","1,89"
 /10.100,"50,00Â %","1,62"
 /15.570, "40,10Â %","3,41"
 /900.310, "8,00Â %","0,10"')
```

### *Input* data in `R` session

```
> dat
# A tibble: 5 × 3
 
  col_1   col_2    col_3
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1 100.432 30,84 % 4,14 
2   3.200 62,89 % 1,89 
3  10.100 50,00 % 1,62 
4  15.570 40,10 % 3,41 
5 900.310  8,00 % 0,10
```

### R code used

```
> dat <- dat %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate_at(
      vars(everything()),
      ~ gsub('[^0-9.]', '', chartr('.,', '_.', .))) %>%
    mutate_at(
      vars(everything()),
      ~ as.numeric(as.character(.)))
```

### Final *output* data

```
> dat
# A tibble: 5 × 3

   col_1 col_2 col_3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 100432  30.8  4.14
2   3200  62.9  1.89
3  10100  50    1.62
4  15570  40.1  3.41
5 900310   8    0.1
```

Thanks to everybody for giving a solution and improving the code.